# Using MERGE in SQL Server 2012 to insert/update data

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have two tables with identical structure. I want to insert new records from table 1 to table 2 if they don't already exist in table 2.

If they already exist, I want to update all of the existing records in table 2.

There are some 30 columns in my tables and I want to update all of them.

Can someone please help with this? I had a look at various links posted over internet, but quite don't understand how my statement should look like.

Comment: [**Complete** and official documentation on `MERGE` in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: I have already read this whole page but I'm still confused.

Comment: Don't try to learn on your 30 column tables. Create some smaller test tables that will be more manageable. Just do update clause, then once you have that try an insert then insert with conditions, etc. Once you are confident repeat in your monster tables

Comment: you know what, you are actually right. i just created a small table and trying to test this but getting some error. see my comments below please

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's really not that hard....

You need:

- a source table (or query) to provide data
- a target table to merge it into
- a condition on which those two tables are checked
- a statement what to do if a match (on that condition) is found
- a statement what to do if NO match (on that condition) is found

So basically, it's something like:

```
-- this is your TARGET table - this is where the data goes into    
MERGE dbo.SomeTable AS target       
-- this is your SOURCE table where the data comes from 
USING dbo.AnotherTable AS source    
-- this is the CONDITION they have to "meet" on
ON (target.SomeColumn = source.AnotherColumn)  

-- if there's a match, so if that row already exists in the target table,
-- then just UPDATE whatever columns in the existing row you want to update
WHEN MATCHED THEN                           
    UPDATE SET Name = source.Name,
               OtherCol = source.SomeCol

-- if there's NO match, that is the row in the SOURCE does *NOT* exist in the TARGET yet,
-- then typically INSERT the new row with whichever columns you're interested in
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)  
    VALUES (source.Val1, source.Val2, ...., source.ValN);
```

Comment: thanks.. im doing this test on a small table first. i creared this table TEST1 and then created a copy of it as TEST2.

CREATE TABLE TEST1
(
ID int,
Name varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
State varchar(255)
)

i am using this to do what i want

MERGE TEST2 AS TARGET       
USING TEST1 AS SOURCE    
ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID  
WHEN MATCHED THEN                           
    UPDATE SET ID=SOURCE.ID,
      Name= SOURCE.Name,
      City= SOURCE.City,
      State= SOURCE.State

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT INTO TEST2
SELECT * FROM TEST1 WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM TEST2)

Comment: also on the internet i see people are using some temporary table to hold the result of the merge statmenet, however i didnt use that in mine. Is it mandatory to do that also?

Comment: ok this one works
     
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (ID, Name, City, State)
VALUES(SOURCE.ID, SOURCE.Name, SOURCE.City, SOURCE.State);

Comment: PS: The only thing I need to know is that if it is mandatory to store the result of MERGE in a temporary table because Im not using it in mine. I am going to use these statements on a production database used to manage transactions and there will be a huge number of records .

Comment: @Newbie: no, you **don't have to** store the results of a `MERGE` statement in a temporary table - quite the contrary - the `MERGE` **updates** (and modifies) the **target table** you define in your `MERGE` statement.....

Comment: @Newbie: also, please **do NOT** post table structure and statements into comments - they cannot be formatted nicely and are next to useless. Instead, **edit your question** and provide the extra information!