# checking if the same row exists in the table or not

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert-update

I am trying to update the table based on the values passed.
I need to check if the same row exists in the table. If it doesn't exist then insert the values into table. If exists the update the particular row of table.

Currently I have written the stored proc to directly enter the values. Any help?

```
Create proc [dbo].[SaveBudgetDetails]
@Quarter nchar(10),
@Year int,
@LineID nvarchar(MAX),
@Project nvarchar(MAX),
@Budget decimal(18,0)
AS
BEGIN

     INSERT INTO [dbo].[BudgetDetails]
           ([Quarter]      
           ,[Year]
          ,[LineID]
          ,[Project]
          ,[Budget])

     VALUES
           ( @Quarter,@Year,@LineID,@Project,@Budget)

END
```

Comment: Another example [Using MERGE in SQL Server 2012 to insert/update data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771416/using-merge-in-sql-server-2012-to-insert-update-data)

Comment: My question is about IF statements. Please check the edited question. It doesn't look like I need to use merge here

Comment: Merge is exactly used for that.. try reading those questions