# SQL Server 2016 Deadlock caused by query?

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Have read all the other deadlock questions, but seems these are typically query-specific, so wasn't able to resolve my particular issue with the posted Answers.

I have a Python script running multiple concurrent UPDATES against this database, and I am getting deadlocks when the thread count is set too high.

The deadlocks are occurring with the query below and I'm not sure what combination of "Table Hints" I'm supposed to use, or if there's a better way to perform this `UPDATE` statement.

Here is my query (with modified names for brevity):

```
BEGIN TRAN
IF EXISTS (SELECT BlahID FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE BlahID = ?)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE MyTable SET
            Foo = ?,
            Bar = 1
        WHERE BlahID = ?
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MyTable (Foo, Bar)
        VALUES (1, ?,)
    END
COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: If you care about accuracy you should drop that NOLOCK hint. Especially since you state it is causing deadlock which indicates other processes are working with this data at the same time. Table hints should only be used when **ALL** other options have been exhausted and you are 100% certain you know what they do. In essence you are stating you know better than the sql engine what type of locking you want.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. However, with it removed, just re-tested and deadlocks occur still.

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to do an "Insert Or Update" for a single row, correct? You should be able to do this in one MERGE statement.

Comment: Correct - updating a single record (Insert or Update). Not the most "SQL savvy" so the posted sql is what I came up with through use of Google Fu. Do you have an example of what a MERGE would look like instead?

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771416/using-merge-in-sql-server-2012-to-insert-update-data

Comment: `NOLOCK` means *ignore others' locks while taking more restrictive locks and returning dirty data*. It's more likely to *cause* deadlocks.

Comment: BTW you *don't* need that `if`at all. You can just leave the `UPDATE` statement as is - if ther'es no matching record, nothing will be modified. You can add a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in the `INSERT` statement to insert only if the ID doesn't exist.

Comment: `MERGE` isn't always a good option anyway, as it's not atomic.

Comment: There's no reason to use the explicit transaction here. The primary reason for using an explicit transaction is to make sure that multiple DML operations either  succeede together fail together. Since there is only 1 DML operation taking place, it's covered automatically by an implicit transaction... While it seems unlikely in this instance, the explicit transaction bay be taking locks earlier than necessary and holding them longer than necessary which would contribute to deaslocking.

Comment: @JasonA.Long that's exactly what happens though - `SELECT` takes shared locks and holds them, then it tries to convert them to UPDATE locks. If another transactions executes the script it will be able to run the SELECt and get S locks. Both transactions will then block on each other's S when they try to upgrade to U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately added a "unique constraint" to the "BlahID" field, as it appears it was performing an entire TABLE-level lock on my first UPDATE statement. Once I added this constraint, I believe it then properly performed only a row-level lock and it resolved the deadlocking issue for me.

I also scrapped the "IF/ELSE" format for my UPDATE and simply do:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET
    Foo = ?
WHERE BlahID = ?
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO MyTable (Foo)
    VALUES (1)
```

I learned a lot about "Table Hints" and locking with the other provided answers, so they are worth a read if you're a wayward Googler!

Comment: You added a unique *index*, not a unique constraint. Unique constraints are implemented by creating a unique index. That's what I meant when I said that you need to have an index on BlahID. If that was the primary key, it would already be indexed. Without that, the server has to lock the entire table because it has to read *all* rows just to find one of them

Comment: BTW `@@ROWCOUNT` is a **bad** idea - it will lead to duplicate entries if two queries get executed for the same ID value. Both queries will pass the `UPDATE` statement without making any modifications so both of them will perform an INSERT without specifying an `ID`, resulting in two new rows

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `IF` to check whether a record already exists. The `WHERE` clause in the UPDATE statement does that. All you need is to ensure a record doesn't exist before *inserting* a new record eg :

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET
    Foo = @foo,
    Bar = 1
WHERE BlahID = @id;

INSERT MyTable (Bar,Foo)
values (1,@foo)
where not exists (select BlahID 
                  from MyTable 
                  where BlahID=@id)
```

Use named parameters if possible so you only need to pass 2 parameters instead of 4 and risk mixing up the order.

You can wrap both statements in a transaction but **Ensure BlahID is indexed**. This will allow the server to lock only a single row for updating. Without an index, the server would have to scan and lock a lot more data to ensure consistency.

This avoids inserting duplicate entries too. No matter how many locks you take, if you use the `IF` clause, two concurrent attempts with the same non-existent ID will result in two insertions because *both* queries will find the row missing, both will try to unconditionally insert.

Another option is to use MERGE, altough it wouldn't perform well in this case. From the [MERGE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017_)

> When simply updating one table based on the rows of another table, improved performance and scalability can be achieved with basic INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. For example:

```
INSERT tbl_A (col, col2)  
SELECT col, col2   
FROM tbl_B   
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT col FROM tbl_A A2 WHERE A2.col = tbl_B.col);
```

The current case is even simpler, there's only one table involved :

```
INSERT MyTable (Bar,Foo)
VALUES (1,@foo)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT BlahID FROM MyTable WHERE BlahID=@id);
```

**Why the deadlock?**

The server has to lock rows to ensure a transaction is repeatable. When selecting, the server takes SHARED (S) locks on retrieved or scanned rows. That's why having an index results in *fewer* locks - the server can find the row it needs immediatelly. Those SHARED locks will remain for the duration of the transaction. If there's no explicit transaction, depending on the isolation mode the shared locks may be preserved for the duration of the connection. That's what happens with REPEATABLE READ.

When you try to update a row,the server will try to take UPDATE locks. If a row has a SHARED lock the server the update operation will be blocked. If a transaction already holds a SHARED lock on a row it will try to upgrade it to an UPGRADE lock. If someone else has an S lock on the row, the transacion will be blocked. For the read to be *repeatable*, the server has to lock the rows it touched.

Things are worse if the server can't locate a single row because of missing indexes.

NOLOCK doesn't mean that no locks are taken, it means that others' locks aren't respected. The operation will still take locks but result in dirty results, ghosts or missing updates.

That's how the dealock is caused in this case :

1. Two connections execute the `IF(SELECT)` and get SHARED locks on the row, S1 and S2.
2. Connection 1 tries to upgrade the lock to UPGRADE but finds S2 lock on it and blocks waiting for it to be released.
3. Connection 2 tries to upgrade to U but finds S1 and blocks. No connection can proceed leading to deadlock.

You can find more about locking, lock types, compatibilites and scope in the [Locking in the Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014-toc/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2014#Lock_Engine) section of the [SQL Server Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014-toc/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2014)

**Snapshot Isolation**

You can use the [snapshot isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server) to avoid readers and writers blocking each other, similar to what Oracle and PostgreSQL do. This won't help in *this* case, because you have one writer blocking another.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want multiple sessions to run the first SELECT for the same key value.  That's what leads to deadlocks.

The correct pattern here is:

```
BEGIN TRAN
IF EXISTS (SELECT BlahID FROM MyTable WITH (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) WHERE BlahID = ?)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE MyTable SET
            Foo = ?,
            Bar = 1
        WHERE BlahID = ?
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MyTable (Foo, Bar)
        VALUES (1, ?,)
    END
COMMIT TRAN
```

The SELECT locks the row if it exists, and acquires an update range lock on the key range if the row doesn't exists.  In both cases a second session will block on the existence check until the first session completes the insert or update.

If you don't read with lock hints (either in a SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT or MERGE), then if the row doesn't exist, no locks will be taken, and multiple sessions may attempt the INSERT.

Comment: Lol at someone DV'ing the Microsoft employee commenting on how to write good SQL.

Comment: This is *awful* SQL - taking excessive locks **causes** deadlocks. The `IF` statement isn't even needed - the UPDATE already has a `WHERE` so it won't execute if there's no match.

Comment: Deadlocks are caused when multiple session first acquire compatible locks, and later attempt to acquire incompatible locks.  So coding transactions to acquire whatever exclusive locks they will eventually need at the beginning is a common way to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: So... what's the verdict? lol. Is the proposed solution good or best to avoid? I didn't know I could/should use both of the LOCK types at once. I guess what's confusing to me with this, is that I'm not wanting to do anything with "BlahID" after selecting, simply using it for the conditional - so my thinking was "don't lock the record since 1) it's a select and 2) i'm "done" with it as soon as it returns the value.

Comment: I really like this user's explanation from another post: "
@SlapY you're saying: "Hey, SQL Server, is there a row with this ID?" SQL Server goes to find the row, perhaps using a scan, and then comes back with "Why, yes, user, I do have a row with that ID!" Then you say, "Okay, SQL Server, go find that row again, but this time, update it!" Do you see how performing the seek or scan twice is wasteful? Can you imagine what happens if another user asks SQL Server the same question about the existence of a row, before you've moved on to doing something about it? – Aaron Bertrand"

Comment: That's a pretty good explanation.   But there's not really a way to do this in a single atomic operation.  You're always searching for the row, and later inserting/updating.  So the important thing is to say "SQL lock this ID, and tell me whether it has any rows."  Then you insert or update accordingly.

Comment: @David, what about this query: UPDATE MyTable SET
                        Foo = ?,
                        Bar = ?
                    WHERE BlahID = ?
                    IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
                        INSERT INTO MyTable (CameraInScan, CameraID)
                        VALUES (1, ?)
This seems to have GREATLY reduced the deadlocks, but not completely. Is it possible the SELECT's in other parts of the application are contributing to the problem?

Comment: That's better than the NOLOCK query, but two sessions can try to update, then try ton insert.  Also if the table has lots of indexes, or the transactions are bigger, then you still might get deadlocks.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft no, two session may try to update without problem but only ONE will insert. Only two seeks will happen per transaction. The difference is that *only one operation will lock*. There's no indexing issue, nodeadlocks, no possibility for duplicate insertion. In fact *a missing* index on BlahID will lead to more locks

Comment: It won’t cause a deadlock, but will cause a PK violation when two sessions concurrently attempt the update and then both attempt the insert.