# Can an upsert (merge statement ) call a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I need to implement a merge statement with updates and inserts and at the same time  I have another condition that if target.x matches with source.x, I have to update a few records in an existing table and insert a new record.

For example: I have a,b,c,d,x as data is there, after checking, if target.x matches wth source.x, condition output should be a,b,c,e,x --- d has to updated to e and a,b,c,d,x

Comment: Hi Hariprasad, do you have any sample code that you can safely share?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MERGE in SQL Server 2012 to insert/update data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771416/using-merge-in-sql-server-2012-to-insert-update-data)